# PyQt5 becomes ugly after building with nuitka

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, nuitka

PyQt5 changes its interface theme after building with nuitka ( this is a tool like pyinstaller ). Here is the comparison:

Before build:

[image]

After build:

[image]

I have couples of buttons and line editors like this, they are all ugly...

OS Info:

- python 3.7
- PyQt5
- windows 10

Comment: Are you using .css file in your code or is your dependent on some other file other than .py to set the theme ?

Comment: @Shubhendu.py No, they're all pure python code without any css file in it.

Answer (score 2):

I add these options and it works for me:

`--plugin-enable=qt-plugins --include-qt-plugins=all --include-qt-plugins=sensible,styles`

Comment: Do you need `sensible,styles`, if you already wrote `--include-qt-plugins=all` prior to that?